# Error in iterating a ul in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium web driver to get the value of a Ul list in a webpage.
Below is my code :

```
waitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='form:item']/ul")));
List<WebElement> links = element.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
System.out.println("Links=="+links.size());//-->2

for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++)
{       
    System.out.println("links-get("+i+")-"+links.get(i));
    System.out.println("==================="+links.get(i).getText());              
}
```

But what ever the size of the list, I get the last element in the list always `(empty String)`. But,if I give the below code, I am getting the correct value:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='form:item']/ul/li[2]")).click();
```

Can anyone please help me in finding the logic mistake in the code. I tried but I am not able to find it.

Below is the HTML snippet :

```
<ul class="xxx">
  <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all">Select  Type</li>
  <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all">Option A</li><li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all">Option B</li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE ** I added a another line like this in the code like below. It fixed the issue. But its so strange. **Can anyone explain why?**

```
waitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='form:item']/ul")));
List<WebElement> links = element.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
System.out.println("Links=="+links.size());//-->2

for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++)
{
    links.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println("links-get("+i+")-"+links.get(i));
    System.out.println("==================="+links.get(i).getText());    
}
```

Comment: can you show us the pages source?

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML as well??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur  Updated the HtmL snippet

Comment: @metar updated the HTML Snippet

Comment: your posted HTML contains 3 li-elements. so why your result is 2?

Make sure you call findElements(By.tagName("li")) in the scope of the correct WebElement. You probably call it on the wrong WebElement (element in your code) which contains only 2 li-Elements.

Comment: Need to share HTML from `<div id = "form:item">`